# Android workmanager job does not run after application close (samsung s9+)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I'm trying to run a one time job with WorkManager. I don't know why but if I close my application from recent app menu job does not start until I start the application :/. Tried with samsung galaxy s9+. Android 9 Pie. Any help would be appreciated. As far as I know workmanager should work even when phone is restarted.

```
 val constraints = Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.NOT_REQUIRED).build()
            val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<NotificationJob>()
                .addTag(item.uniqueId)
                .setInputData(data)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                    //TODO revert
//                .setInitialDelay(warrantyItem.reminderDate - System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .setInitialDelay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build()
            WorkManager.getInstance(this@MainActivity).enqueue(request)
```

job is pretty simple. Just notification:

```
 override fun doWork(): Result {
        // Get the input
        val uniqueId = inputData.getString(JOB_KEY)
        if (uniqueId != null) {
            sendNotification(uniqueId, "title", "subtitle")
        }


        return Result.success()
    }

    private fun sendNotification(uniqueId: String, title: String, subtitle: String) {
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, id)

        val notificationManager =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val bitmap = applicationContext.vectorToBitmap(R.drawable.ic_warranty_icon)
        val titleNotification = "$title"
        val subtitleNotification = subtitle
        val pendingIntent = getActivity(applicationContext, 0, intent, 0)
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)
            .setLargeIcon(bitmap).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_warranty_icon)
            .setContentTitle(titleNotification).setContentText(subtitleNotification)
            .setDefaults(DEFAULT_ALL).setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true)

        notification.priority = PRIORITY_MAX

        if (SDK_INT >= O) {
            notification.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)

            val ringtoneManager = getDefaultUri(TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
            val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
                .setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION).build()

            val channel =
                NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL, NOTIFICATION_NAME, IMPORTANCE_HIGH)

            channel.enableLights(true)
            channel.lightColor = RED
            channel.enableVibration(true)
            channel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
            channel.setSound(ringtoneManager, audioAttributes)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)) {
            // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
            notify(uniqueId, ID, notification.build())
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hello! Are you sending "JOB_KEY" string value to the work manager?

Comment: Yes, everything is working correctly while app is not closed

Comment: If you are testing your application launching it from Android Studio, it may behave differently than launching from the device.

Said that, it would be useful to have more logging information as explained in this codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-adv-workmanager/#3